# How to add a navigation bar and UIButton to a UIView that slides from bottom

Tags: iphone, uiview

Below is the code where I show a `UIView` from under a toolbar. It is displayed by clicking a button on toolbar. Now I want to add a button to the `UIView` that pops up , so as to cancel it. If possible a button over navigation bar which makes the UI better?
Can anyone point me towards a tutorial or so?

```
-(void)likeButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)button
 {                                                
     CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 480, 320, 190);
     frame.origin.y = CGRectGetMaxY(self.optionsToolBar.frame)-frame.size.height;   
     bottomView.frame = frame;
     [self.optionsToolBar.superview insertSubview:bottomView              
                                      belowSubview:self.optionsToolBar];
 }
```

Comment: are you adding view from xib or from code?

Comment: i m adding view from code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 -(void)likeButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)button
  {                                                
      CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 480, 320, 190);
      frame.origin.y = CGRectGetMaxY(self.optionsToolBar.frame)-frame.size.height;   
      bottomView.frame = frame;

      UIView *navigationView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)]; 
      [navigationView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
      UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
      [button setTitle:@"close" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      [button addTarget:self action:@selector(closeView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
      [navigationView addSubView:button];
      [bottomView addSubView:navigationView];

      [self.optionsToolBar.superview insertSubview:bottomView              
                                  belowSubview:self.optionsToolBar];

  }


  - (void) closeView :(id)sender{
      [[sender superView] removeFromSuperView];          
  }
```